# MKS Integrity list all files from sandbox and their Member Rev

Tags: integrity, mks

is there a way that I could list all files from my sandbox with their Member Rev. by using si.exe?

Beside this, are there any special rights required in order to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using:

```
si viewsandbox
Enter sandbox name: d:\DELETEME\SB1\project.pj
Do you want to recurse into the subproject d:\DELETEME\SB1\watch\project.pj? [ynYN](n): y
 d:\DELETEME\SB1\watch\project.pj (d1) variant-subsandbox
   d:\DELETEME\SB1\watch\AISubsystem.txt archived 1.3
   d:\DELETEME\SB1\watch\ConversionTool.asm archived 1.1
   d:\DELETEME\SB1\watch\ExceptionHandler.asm archived 1.1
   d:\DELETEME\SB1\watch\StructureImplementation.java archived 1.6
   d:\DELETEME\SB1\watch\dataStructure.txt archived 1.2
   d:\DELETEME\SB1\watch\findSmallestInput.asm archived 1.1
```